# When publishing Visual Studio Code extensions, is there something similar to vscode:prepublish for post-publish operations?

Tags: visual-studio-code, npm, vscode-extensions, package.json

When developing a VSCode extension, in `package.json` we can define a `vscode:prepublish` task that is executed before publishing using `vsce publish`:

```
"scripts": {
  "vscode:prepublish": "myPrepublishingScript.sh",
  ...
}
```

Can I define a task/script that should be executed post-publish?

Currently we have a `publish.sh` script that executes `vsce publish && postpublish.sh` but I would like to get rid of this `publish.sh` script.

Comment: Please post a feature request to https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues If you are not one of the rare members requesting this, it should get enough votes to be considered.

Comment: if you do create a feature-request issue ticket, please [edit] your question post to link to it for posterity.